# Getting value of radio button from dynamic form

Tags: html, jsp, radio-button

I have a form within a JSP that contains a multiple choice quiz, each question is followed by a group of radio buttons with the options, these are pulled from the database as questions don't all have the same number of options and the radio buttons are added as the form is created, each radio button has a label which contains the text answer. When submitting the page it is passed to another JSP, here I want to get the text from the label to store so I can check the answers.

here's the form, so each group of radio buttons is given the name based on question number, and each member of the group is given a id based on its question number and option within the question.

```
<form class="container" id="quiz" method="post" action="/quizChecker.jsp">
  <% for (int i = 0; i < ques_nos.size(); i++) {
    String query = "SELECT answer_text, is_correct FROM Quiz_Question_Option WHERE quiz_ques_id = ?";
    PreparedStatement prepstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    prepstmt.setInt(1, ques_nos.get(i));
    ResultSet rsq = prepstmt.executeQuery();
    rsq.last();
    int size = rsq.getRow();
    rsq.first();
    %>
    <p id="ques" class="Question"<%=i%>"><%=questions.get(i)%></p><br>
    <% for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    %>
    <input class="checkmark" type="radio" name="q<%=i%>" id="q<%=i%><%=j%>">
    <label for="q<%=i%><%=j%>"><%=rsq.getString(1)%></label><br>
    <% rsq.next();
  }
}
session.setAttribute("ques", ques_nos);
%>
<button type="submit" value="checkQuiz">Submit Quiz</button>
</form>
```

Here's the code where I was trying to get the text value of the selected button.

```
<%
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<~>(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String given = request.getParameter("q"+i);
    answers.add(given);
}
...
```

When I added a loop to print out what had been added to answers it returned "ononononon" so I guess I am accessing if the button is selected, as I would only be looking at selected radio buttons here, how do I get the value of the label instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a value for all the radio buttons

```
<input class="checkmark" value="answer1" type="radio" name="q<%=i%>" id="q<%=i%><%=j%>">
<input class="checkmark" value="answer2" type="radio" name="q<%=i%>" id="q<%=i%><%=j%>">
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems really simple now! I just set the value to the same as the label text.